# How to recover after ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, exception

I have several long-running threads in an MVC3 application that are meant to run forever.

I'm running into a problem where a ThreadAbortException is being called by some other code (not mine) and I need to recover from this gracefully and restart the thread. Right now, our only recourse is to recycle the worker process for the appDomain, which is far from ideal.

**Here's some details about this code works:**

A singleton service class exists for this MVC3 application. It has to be a singleton because it caches data. This service is responsible for making request to a database. A 3rd party library is used for the actual database connection code.

In this singleton class we use a collection of classes that are called "QueryRequestors". These classes identify unique package+stored_procedure names for requests to the database, so that we can queue those calls. That is the purpose of the QueryRequestor class: to make sure calls to the same package+stored_procedure (although they may have infinite different parameters) are queued, and do not happen simultaneously. This eases our database strain considerably and improves performance.

The QueryRequestor class uses an internal BlockingCollection and an internal Task (thread) to monitor its queue (blocking collection). When a request comes into the singleton service, it finds the correct QueryRequestor class via the package+stored_procedure name, and it hands the query over to that class. The query gets put in the queue (blocking collection). The QueryRequestor's Task sees there's a request in the queue and makes a call to the database (now the 3rd party library is involved). When the results come back they are cached in the singleton service. The Task continues processing requests until the blocking collection is empty, and then it waits.

Once a QueryRequestor is created and up and running, we never want it to die. Requests come in to this service 24/7 every few minutes. If the cache in the service has data, we use it. When data is stale, the very next request gets queued (and subsequent simultaneous requests continue to use the cache, because they know someone (another thread) is already making a queued request, and this is efficient).

So the issue here is what to do when the Task inside a QueryRequestor class encounters a ThreadAbortException. Ideally I'd like to recover from that and restart the thread. Or, at the very least, dispose of the QueryRequestor (it's in a "broken" state now as far as I'm concerned) and start over. Because the next request that matches the package+stored_procedure name will create a new QueryRequestor if one is not present in the service.

I suspect the thread is being killed by the 3rd party library, but I can't be certain. All I know is that nowhere do *I* abort or attempt to kill the thread/task. I want it to run forever. But clearly we have to have code in place for this exception. It's very annoying when the service bombs because a thread has been aborted.

What is the best way to handle this? How can we handle this gracefully?

Comment: You might find this link useful: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can stop re-throwing of `ThreadAbortException` by calling [Thread.ResetAbort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort.aspx).

Note that most common case of the exception is Redirect call, and canceling thread abort may case undesired effects of execution of request code that otherwise would be ignored due to killing the thread. It is common issue in WinForms (where separation of code and rendering is less clear) than in MVC (where you can return special redirect results from controllers).

Comment: I don't want to stop rethrowing. I just want to deal with it gracefully. I figured something out shortly after posting this question. I'll have to put the answer up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with for a solution, and it works quite nicely.

The real issue here isn't preventing the ThreadAbortException, because you can't prevent it anyway, and we don't want to prevent it. It's actually a good thing if we get an error report telling us this happened. We just don't want our app coming down because of it.

So, what we really needed was a graceful way to handle this Exception without bringing down the application.

The solution I came up with was to create a bool flag property on the QueryRequestor class called "IsValid". This property is set to true in the constructor of the class.

In the DoWork() call that is run on the separate thread in the QueryRequestor class, we catch the ThreadAbortException and we set this flag to FALSE. Now we can tell other code that this class is in an Invalid (broken) state and not to use it.

So now, the singleton service that makes use of this QueryRequestor class knows to check for this IsValid property. If it's not valid, it replaces the QueryRequestor with a new one, and life moves on. The application doesn't crash and the broken QueryRequestor is thrown away, replaced with a new version that can do the job.

In testing, this worked quite well. I would intentionally call Thread.Abort() on the DoWork() thread, and watch the Debug window for output lines. The app would report that the thread had been aborted, and then the singleton service was correctly replacing the QueryRequestor. The replacement was then able to successfully handle the request.